# How to create a python distribution package in Eclipse pyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Using the Pydev plugin I can create packages that work well within Eclipse.
However, I want to create packages that I can import in other environments.

How would I proceed to do that?
(any chance I can just right click the package name in eclipse, and "export to package? :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does export to package mean for you? If you just take the package, the way it is and copy it to `site-packages` it will work out of the box, in principle.

What you probably want is something like [`python setup.py bdist`](http://docs.python.org/distutils/builtdist.html). AFAIK, you've got to do this by hand. (And it's easy, really!)